# Symfony save user to session user data lost

Tags: php, forms, symfony, session

I'm creating a multi step form in Symfony 3.3 where I save the form data each step to a session. The entity of the form also has the user as form property. When the user is added to the entity, all data is saved correctly to the session. But when I submit the form and then load the data from session again, most of the data of the user (as form property of entity) is gone. Only the username, id, passwordEncoded is in session, all other variables of the user (firstName, lastName, email, ...) is NULL. It is the same when I save only the user to the session. Is there something which I have to do after saving the user to session? Why is the data of the user lost after reloading the page?

Thanks and best!

Entity\User:

```
class User extends EntitySuperclass implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     *
     * @Assert\Length(max=4096,groups={"account_complete","account_password","user"})
     * @Assert\Length(min = 8,groups={"account_complete","account_password","user"}, minMessage="user.password_length")
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * The below length depends on the "algorithm" you use for encoding
     * the password, but this works well with bcrypt.
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"account_register","user"})
     * @Assert\Email(
     *      groups = {"account_register", "account","user"},
     *      strict = true,
     *      checkMX = true
     * )
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $emailNew = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Salutation")
     * 
     */
    private $salutation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"account_complete","user"})
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9 ]+$/",groups={"account_complete","user"}, message="user.first_name.regex")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"account_complete","user"})
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜß0-9 ]+$/",groups={"account_complete","user"}, message="user.last_name.regex")
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email_confirmed", type="boolean")
     */
    private $emailConfirmed = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $shibbolethState = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $shibbolethHash = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $shibbolethPersistentId = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserGroup")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_UserGroup",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $userGroups;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $confirmationEmailSend;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $lastLogin = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $expires = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $sessionId = '';

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BankDetails", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_BankDetails",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bank_details_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $bankDetails;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Address", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="User_BillingAddress",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="billing_address_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     * @Assert\Count(
     *      min = 1,
     *      minMessage = "user.billing_addresses.min",
     * )
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $billingAddresses;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->confirmationEmailSend = 0;
        $this->userGroups = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->bankDetails = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->billingAddresses = new ArrayCollection();
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $currentTimestamp = time();

        if($this->getConfirmationEmailSend() == NULL)
            $this->setConfirmationEmailSend(0);

   }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        //return $this->username;
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // The bcrypt algorithm doesn't require a separate salt.
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = array();
        $userGroups = $this->getUserGroups();
        if(!empty($userGroups)) {
            foreach($userGroups as $userGroup) {
                $role = $userGroup->getRole();
                $roles[] = 'ROLE_'.strtoupper($role);
            }
        }
        return $roles;
    }

    public function isGranted($role)
    {
        return in_array($role, $this->getRoles());
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->setUsername($email);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Add userGroup
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserGroup $userGroup
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addUserGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\UserGroup $userGroup)
    {
        $this->userGroups[] = $userGroup;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove userGroup
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserGroup $userGroup
     */
    public function removeUserGroup(\AppBundle\Entity\UserGroup $userGroup)
    {
        $this->userGroups->removeElement($userGroup);
    }

    /**
     * Get userGroups
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUserGroups()
    {
        return $this->userGroups;
    }

    /**
     * Set shibbolethPersistentId
     *
     * @param string $shibbolethPersistentId
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setShibbolethPersistentId($shibbolethPersistentId)
    {
        $this->shibbolethPersistentId = $shibbolethPersistentId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shibbolethPersistentId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShibbolethPersistentId()
    {
        return $this->shibbolethPersistentId;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set emailConfirmed
     *
     * @param boolean $emailConfirmed
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmailConfirmed($emailConfirmed)
    {
        $this->emailConfirmed = $emailConfirmed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emailConfirmed
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getEmailConfirmed()
    {
        return $this->emailConfirmed;
    }

    public function removeAllUserGroups() {
        $userGroups = $this->getUserGroups();
        foreach($userGroups as $userGroup) {
           $this->removeUserGroup($userGroup);
        }
    }

    public function hasUserGroup($userGroupId) {
        foreach($this->getUserGroups() as $userGroup) {
            if($userGroup->getId() == $userGroupId)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastLogin
     *
     * @param integer $lastLogin
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastLogin($lastLogin)
    {
        $this->lastLogin = $lastLogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastLogin
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getLastLogin()
    {
        return $this->lastLogin;
    }

    /**
     * Set confirmationEmailSend
     *
     * @param integer $confirmationEmailSend
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setConfirmationEmailSend($confirmationEmailSend)
    {
        $this->confirmationEmailSend = $confirmationEmailSend;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get confirmationEmailSend
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getConfirmationEmailSend()
    {
        return $this->confirmationEmailSend;
    }

    /**
     * Set validTill
     *
     * @param integer $validTill
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setValidTill($validTill)
    {
        $this->validTill = $validTill;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get validTill
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getValidTill()
    {
        return $this->validTill;
    }

    /**
     * Set shibbolethValid
     *
     * @param integer $shibbolethValid
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setShibbolethValid($shibbolethValid)
    {
        $this->shibbolethValid = $shibbolethValid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shibbolethValid
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getShibbolethValid()
    {
        return $this->shibbolethValid;
    }

    /**
     * Set shibbolethHash
     *
     * @param string $shibbolethHash
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setShibbolethHash($shibbolethHash)
    {
        $this->shibbolethHash = $shibbolethHash;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shibbolethHash
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getShibbolethHash()
    {
        return $this->shibbolethHash;
    }

    /**
     * Set shibbolethState
     *
     * @param integer $shibbolethState
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setShibbolethState($shibbolethState)
    {
        $this->shibbolethState = $shibbolethState;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shibbolethState
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getShibbolethState()
    {
        return $this->shibbolethState;
    }

    /**
     * Set expires
     *
     * @param integer $expires
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setExpires($expires)
    {
        $this->expires = $expires;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get expires
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getExpires()
    {
        return $this->expires;
    }

    /**
     * Set emailNew
     *
     * @param string $emailNew
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmailNew($emailNew)
    {
        $this->emailNew = $emailNew;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emailNew
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailNew()
    {
        return $this->emailNew;
    }

    /**
     * Set passwordHash
     *
     * @param string $passwordHash
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPasswordHash($passwordHash)
    {
        $this->passwordHash = $passwordHash;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get passwordHash
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPasswordHash()
    {
        return $this->passwordHash;
    }

    /**
     * Set sessionId
     *
     * @param string $sessionId
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSessionId($sessionId)
    {
        $this->sessionId = $sessionId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sessionId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSessionId()
    {
        return $this->sessionId;
    }

    /**
     * Set salutation
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Salutation $salutation
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalutation(\AppBundle\Entity\Salutation $salutation = null)
    {
        $this->salutation = $salutation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get salutation
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Salutation
     */
    public function getSalutation()
    {
        return $this->salutation;
    }

    /**
     * Add bankDetail
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BankDetails $bankDetail
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addBankDetail(\AppBundle\Entity\BankDetails $bankDetail)
    {
        $this->bankDetails[] = $bankDetail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove bankDetail
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\BankDetails $bankDetail
     */
    public function removeBankDetail(\AppBundle\Entity\BankDetails $bankDetail)
    {
        $this->bankDetails->removeElement($bankDetail);
    }

    /**
     * Get bankDetails
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getBankDetails()
    {
        return $this->bankDetails;
    }

    /**
     * Add billingAddress
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addBillingAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        $this->billingAddresses[] = $billingAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove billingAddress
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     */
    public function removeBillingAddress(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        $this->billingAddresses->removeElement($billingAddress);
    }

    /**
     * Set billingAddresses
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     *
     * @return User
     * 
     */
    public function setBillingAddresses(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        if($this->billingAddresses !== NULL and $this->billingAddresses->contains($billingAddress)){
            return false;
        }
        $this->addBillingAddress($billingAddress);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set one billingAddresses
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     *
     * @return User
     * 
     */
    public function setOneBillingAddresses(\AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress)
    {
        $this->billingAddresses = $billingAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set one billingAddresses
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Address $billingAddress
     *
     * @return User
     * 
     */
    public function unsetBillingAddresses()
    {
        $this->billingAddresses = new ArrayCollection();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get billingAddresses
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getBillingAddresses()
    {
        return $this->billingAddresses;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Only the username, id, passwordEncoded is in session, all other variables of the user (firstName, lastName, email, ...) is NULL. It is the same when I save only the user to the session. Is there something which I have to do after saving the user to session?* - Take a look at the `serialize` and `unserialize` functions of your class, it's up in there.

Comment: In short: Only the infos needed to restore the entity from the database are serialized. If you need more fields, add them to those calls.

Comment: How do I add more fields to the call? If I call e. g. getFirstName() with the entity from the session I also got NULL.

Comment: I also have the entity billing addresses, which is added in the multi step form. But after submission of the form the entered billing address is also gone in the session and I also cannot get it by Doctrine. Do I have to flush the billing address directly after form submission? So what to do if I change a property of the user? Do I directly have to flush them?